# fatal: unable to connect to code.in.tum.de:

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,
I'm trying to install the JNI version of rosjava, and am getting connection failure. Anyone have an idea what's going on with the host site?  I've tried three different ways: git, git via rosws set, and sudo.  I don't know why the sudo approach failed, but I'm guessing it might the same connection issue.
Thanks in advance for any help offered.
My steps and terminal output are below.

```
hq@ubuntu:/opt/ros/fuerte$ roscd
hq@ubuntu:~/fuerte_workspace$ ls
hq@ubuntu:~/fuerte_workspace$ git clone -b cturtle_released git://code.in.tum.de/git/client-rosjava.git client_rosjava
Cloning into 'client_rosjava'...
fatal: unable to connect to code.in.tum.de:
code.in.tum.de[0: 131.159.18.84]: errno=Connection timed out

hq@ubuntu:~/fuerte_workspace$ rosws set client_rosjava --git  git://code.in.tum.de/git/client-rosjava.git

     Add new elements:
  client_rosjava    git  git://code.in.tum.de/git/client-rosjava.git   

Continue: (y)es, (n)o: y
Overwriting /home/hq/fuerte_workspace/.rosinstall

Do not forget to do ...
$ source /home/hq/fuerte_workspace/setup.sh
... in every open terminal.
Config changed, remember to run 'rosws update client_rosjava' to update the folder from git
hq@ubuntu:~/fuerte_workspace$ rosws update client_rosjava
[client_rosjava] Installing git://code.in.tum.de/git/client-rosjava.git (version None) to /home/hq/fuerte_workspace/client_rosjava
WARNING [vcstools] Command failed: 'git clone --recursive git://code.in.tum.de/git/client-rosjava.git /home/hq/fuerte_workspace/client_rosjava'
 errcode: 128:
fatal: unable to connect to code.in.tum.de:
code.in.tum.de[0: 131.159.18.84]: errno=Connection timed out

[/vcstools]
Exception caught during install: Error processing 'client_rosjava' : [client_rosjava] Checkout of git://code.in.tum.de/git/client-rosjava.git version None into /home/hq/fuerte_workspace/client_rosjava failed.

ERROR: Error processing 'client_rosjava' : [client_rosjava] Checkout of git://code.in.tum.de/git/client-rosjava.git version None into /home/hq/fuerte_workspace/client_rosjava failed.

hq@ubuntu:~/fuerte_workspace$ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-rosjava-jni
[sudo] password for hq: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-fuerte-rosjava-jni
hq@ubuntu:~/fuerte_workspace$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47274/fatal:-unable-to-connect-to-code.in.tum.de:/) by [HQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/3513/hq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-11-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/3513/hq/) on 2012-11-02**:
Thanks for the help, Lorenz! You're probably correct that my company's firewall is the cause of the problem.  I installed from the debian packages as you suggested and it worked. I'm new to the ROS world and it's great to have help like this.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So for me, the checkout of the git repository works. Either it was a server hickup on our side and it is working again or the server is blocked maybe by a firewall or something like that on your side. But if you can, you should install from debian packages anyway. The reason why that didn't work for you is that your package name was incorrect. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-client-rosjava-jni
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2